How do I eliminate line breaks and carriage returns in notepad++
I have the following address in Notepad++ and I want to change it to single line:
2400 Highway 31 SW

FooBar

AL

37770


Using find/replace so that the result looks like this:
2400 Highway 31 SW FooBar AL 37770



https://superuser.com/q/518229/157002

If you wanted to avoid spaces at the end of the string you could replace \R+(\z)? with (?1: ). The end of the string \z is captured to group 1. In the replacement conditional if the first group matches we replace with empty space, else with a space. Here is a PCRE2 demo (slightly different syntax).

You should be able to do this with a repeated combination of "CR? + LF":

Press: Ctrl + H (Replace)

Find what: (\r?\n)\1
Replace with:  
Search mode: Regular expression





Ctrl+H
Find what: \R
Replace with:    # a space
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

